# How to use python groupby()

Tags: python, python-itertools

When I try to use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group a list of numbers like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for key, value in groupby(a):
    print((len(list(value)), key), end=' ')
```

The output is

```
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 1) (1, 3) (1, 2) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5)
```

instead of

```
(3, 1) (3, 2) (2, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5)
```

Why doesn't it group identical numbers correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grouping input by common key elements with [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) only works on input already sorted by that key:

> [...] Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

Your example should work like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = sorted([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for key, value in groupby(a):
    print((len(list(value)), key), end=' ')
```

If you use `groupby()` on unorderd input you'll get a new group every time a different key is returned by the `key` function while iterating through the iterable.

Comment: `groupby` groups consecutive elements.  It expects a sorted input, but it works on unsorted inputs too, if consecutive sub-groups is deserved.

Comment: @pylang You're right, `groupby()` does work on input not already sorted on the keyfunc, and there are good use cases for that. I've changed my answer not to sound like it wouldn't work with such input at all while it does, altough the result isn't what you'd trivially expect from a `groupby()` function - but on the other hand implicitly sorting the input of a iterable would be worse (eliminate that use case and would not work on infinite iterables).

Comment: That works.  Also, there's a typo in my comment.  I meant "desired", not "deserved".

Comment: Check this out: `list((k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a))`.

Comment: I don't know who design this stupid API, `You have to sort your data first.` before groupby. Why not let me design and make a CPU by myself before use python?

Comment: @JokeHuang Since `groupby()` takes an iterator as input, this is actually the only *not* stupid way this can be implemented.  Who says the content fits into memory to be sorted? Something like `itertools.groupby(range(10**20), lambda i: i // 100)` works without problems. Sorting it would not be possible, as you'd need to dump it to memory to do so, and additionally also unnecessary, as it's already sorted. But the algorithm couldn't know that in advance. Leaving it up to the caller to sort the input if that's needed and possible is a sane choice.

Comment: @mata Use a dict-like things to store the items into same group will not depends the sorting operation. And why C# `GroupBy` do not need sorting first? It use a iterator-like(IEnumerable) thing as input too. This can only show that the designer is stupid.

Comment: @JokeHuang I'd be curious what happens if you give it an infinite enumerable, really. Don't know much about C#, so please try it and tell me what happens.

Comment: @mata Who will give an infinite enumerable to `groupby`?

Comment: @JokeHuang That's not the point. `itertools.groupby` supports that. Does C# GroupBy?

Comment: @mata Not, but this is a rare needs. Sacrificing ease of use to meet rare needs is obviously a stupid decision.

Comment: @JokeHuang So you'd rather sacrifice functionality instead? Not sure if we have the same concept of what's stupid. If it wasn't part of `itertools` and only worked with sized collections or sequences then I might follow your reasoning.

Comment: @mata I will design to add standalone interface or a parameter for infinite iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your output requirement, I'll change your question. [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is simple to use here

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[ (v, k) for k, v in Counter(a).items() ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.groupby` only group the consecutive elements. So you need to sort before doing `groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = sorted([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for key, value in groupby(a):
    print((len(list(value)), key), end=' ')
```

**Result**

```
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(2, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
```